# How to concatenate different values in different columns in a new column?

Tags: r

suppose I have something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                  value = c(1, 2, 3))
```

I would like to add an extra column in which I have a value like this:
[A,1]

It would be a column in which each single values are the concatenation of "[" + A (value in the first column) + "," + B (value in the second column) + "]".
How can I do it? I tried with paste but I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `dat$Con <- paste("[",dat$ID,",",dat$value,"]", sep="")` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that will work consistently with endless numbers of columns:

```
dat$conc <- paste0("[",apply(dat,1,paste,collapse=","),"]")
```

---

Using your example:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), value = c(1, 2, 3))
dat$conc <- paste0("[",apply(dat,1,paste,collapse=","),"]")
```

Gives:

```
  ID value  conc
1  A     1 [A,1]
2  B     2 [B,2]
3  C     3 [C,3]
```

Or if we have a dataframe with more columns:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), value = c(1, 2, 3), value2 = c(4, 5, 6))
dat$conc <- paste0("[",apply(dat,1,paste,collapse=","),"]")
```

Gives:

```
  ID value value2    conc
1  A     1      4 [A,1,4]
2  B     2      5 [B,2,5]
3  C     3      6 [C,3,6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is your data

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), value = c(1, 2, 3))
```

This would work

```
dat$concat <- paste0("[", dat$ID, ", ", dat$value, "]")

  ID value concat
1  A     1 [A, 1]
2  B     2 [B, 2]
3  C     3 [C, 3]
```

Or if you did not want the space after the comma:

```
dat$concat <- paste0("[", dat$ID, ",", dat$value, "]")
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like to introduce an upgrade to the original question: What if I want to concatenate as you said, but instead of the values, I want to concatenate the percentage of that value across the single row. Let say I have a dat<-data.frame(x1=c(1), x2=c(4), x3=c(5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE). I would like to have a concatenate value in the dat$concat like this: [10,40,50] (each value is the percentage now)

Comment: If you have a new question please create a new question. However, it seems that the other answer by @lookitsme would almost get you there.